# $\frac{d J}{d \alpha}$ or $\frac{\partial J}{\partial \alpha}$ in variational calculus

Tags: calculus-of-variations

We've a functional

$J(\alpha)=\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}} f\left\{y(\alpha, x), y^{\prime}(\alpha, x) ; x\right\} d x$

It's derivative with respect to the parameter $\alpha$ is given in textbook *Classical Dynamics of Particles and Systems by Stephen T. Thornton and Jerry B. Marion*,as $\frac{\partial J}{\partial \alpha}$

Shouldn't it have been $\frac{d J}{d \alpha}$ ?
I'd read that partial notation is used when other variables are kept constant, here after the integral is performed the only variable remaining is $\alpha$ so the $\frac{d J}{d \alpha}$  notation seems appropriate. Is it true?

Comment: others use $\dfrac{\delta J}{\delta\alpha}$

Comment: Id read that partial notation is used when other variables are kept constant, here after the integral the only variable remaining is $\alpha$

Comment: beyond the symbolism is the definition, to get the real juice from

Comment: But it confuses introductory students :(

Comment: that is part of the trainings! once one realizes that it's going to be easy read anything

Comment: Thank you, that's true. As a request, am I correct what I said in the question?

Comment: read this to get strong https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative

Comment: Consider it done. Sir. :)

Answer (score 1):

As an exercise let me deliver here these three expressions:

1. For a function $f=f(t)$ we write
   $$\frac{df(a)}{dt}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(a+t)-f(a)}{t}$$
2. For a function on several variables $F=F(x,y)$. we have
   $$\frac{\partial F(a,b)}{\partial x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{F(a+x,b)-F(a,b)}{x}\quad {\rm and}\quad \frac{\partial F(a,b)}{\partial y}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{F(a,b+y)-F(a,b)}{y}.$$
3. But for functional integral $J=\int_a^bL(x,y,y')dx$ we consider
   $$\frac{\delta J(x,y,y')}{\delta \varepsilon}=
   \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_a^b \frac{L(x,y+\varepsilon h,y'+\varepsilon h')-L(x,y,y')}{\varepsilon}\ dx,
   $$
   where $y=y(x)$ and $h=h(x)$ is took in such a way that satisfies $h(a)=h(b)=0$.